"Issues Running FHIR PIT Tutorial Code in R"
I was working through the tutorial [(https://niehs.github.io/PCOR_bookdown_staging/chapter-fhir-pit.html)] but encountered issues when trying to run the following code chunks:
mkdir -p $WORK_DIR
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ExposuresProvider/FHIR-PIT.git $WORK_DIR

echo "$WORK_DIR/data/output"

docker run -m=4g -v "$WORK_DIR/data/output":"/FHIR-PIT/data/output" renci/fhir-pit:1.0

year_ <- 2010
basepath <- file.path(work_dir, "data", "output")
icees2dei_patient_url <- file.path(basepath, "icees2_dei", sprintf("%spatient_deidentified", year_))


icees2dei_colorder <- scan("icees2dei_patient_column_order.txt", what = "", sep = "\n")

icees2dei <- read.csv(icees2dei_patient_url,header = TRUE)[, icees2dei_colorder]
icees2dei

ggplot(icees2dei, aes(y = AvgDailyPM2.5Exposure, x = MaxDailyOzoneExposure)) +
    geom_point(color = "blue") +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)

Could someone please try running these code snippets and let me know if you are able to perform them successfully? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

The 4 lines starting mkdir -p $WORK_DIR till docker run... are not code chunks in R. Those are system commands you have to execute in bash terminal. The first one creates a directory, the second clones the github content and the 4th runs the docker, which pulls necessary components and run the calculations.
